MySQL Workbench error –“could not connect, server may not be running”
MySQL Workbench error screenshot
Went on to services and MYSQL80 was not running so I right clicked > properties then tried to start on automatic and manual and got an error message “The MYSQL80 service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs”:
Services error screenshot
I watched a youtube video that told me to use command prompt and run as administrator and navigate to bin folder of MySQL and type mysqld –initialize however when I press enter nothing happens? After pressing enter a new line of  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin> appears?
Screenshot of What I tried in command prompt
Please help ☹ I just want to use MySQL

Unfortunately, there can be hundred and one reason why mysql service does not properly start. You need to check the mysql and windows error logs first to get an idea. Also unfortunately for you, this question is not about programming, but about database admin, therefore it is off topic here on SO. dba.stackexchange.com sister site of SO can provide you with help, but they will need to see the actual error as well.

@Shadow Thank you. I will use the sister site. How do I get the actual error?

By examining mysql / windows logs
